# Scraping 'offers' data from OpenSea

Tags: web-scraping, blockchain, scrapinghub, opensea

I want to scarpe/download the data from OpenSea regarding offers/bid.
Any suggestions/solutions on how can I do this?
For example: I want to download the offers from 'https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0xc6211c8b3f89e205c46a6f3f2e99d20a7da0f684/6'

I tried to look on the Opensea developer tools, no end points around NFT allow me to download this data ( it's not available )